# R: Httr package - connection with API, Error 1200: description" : "__all__ : img or url parameter is needed

Tags: r, api, httr

I am very newbie in HTTR and connection with API by R. I cannot connect with F.A.C.E API (documentation: https://face-api.sightcorp.com/dev-documentation/)

```
library(httr)
library("XML")
library("jsonlite")
library(RCurl)

key = 'XXX'
img = 'C:\\my_image.jpg'

The query:
my_json <- POST('https://api-face.sightcorp.com/api/detect/', add_headers(app_key = key, img = img, ethnicity = TRUE ))
print(my_json)
```

and the answer:

```
Response [https://api-face.sightcorp.com/api/detect/]
  Date: 2019-02-19 20:26
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 88 B
{
  "error_code" : 1200,
  "description" : "__all__ : img or url parameter is needed."
```

How shall I implement img or url adress into the code to obtain API analysis?

Comment: You are passing values in the header, not the body of the post as indicated by the documentation.

Comment: So... how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

```
my_body = list('app_key'=key, 'img'= upload_file(img.url))
my_json <- POST('https://api-face.sightcorp.com/api/detect/',body = my_body)
```